# Rotated contenteditable moves while user typing

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, css-transforms

I have a content editable that can be rotated by the user. The size of the element is `auto` which means it's changes it's size as you type in it. The problem is that if you type something in it while it's rotated, it moves
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Buywa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the rotation is agains the `transform-origin`, which by default is `50% 50%`. When the size is changing, the point of rotation also changes, and this causes the movement. You can fix the point of rotation by setting the `transform-origin` field in pixels. It won't move while you are typing, but if you attempt to change the rotation, it won't be around the element center (assuming the element center has changed since you've set it).

So before changing the rotation angle, you need to reset `transform-origin` to the center of the element, but as soon as you do it, the position of the element would change, so you need to correct the position as well. Get the difference of the positions of the bounding box before and after the change of `transform-origin` and add it to the element coordinates. Here is some code (written with Mootools framework)

```
 var correctRotatedElementPosition = function (element) {
      var old_position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      var center = '50% 50%';
      element.setStyles({
         'transform-origin'         : center,
         '-webkit-transform-origin' : center,
         '-ms-transform-origin'     : center
      });

      var new_position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

      var current_coordinates = element.getStyles(['left', 'top']);

      var delta_left = old_position.left.toInt() - new_position.left.toInt();
      var delta_top  = old_position.top.toInt() - new_position.top.toInt();

      this.element.setStyles({
         'left'              : current_coordinates.left.toInt() + delta_left,
         'top'               : current_coordinates.top.toInt() + delta_top
      });
   }
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to calculate and set the center point of the div as transform-origin?